# What is happening with Harley Quinn in rebirth?

Tags: dc, comics, dc-rebirth, harley-quinn

In her own Rebirth comic, she is free to roam, but in the *Suicide Squad: rebirth* comic, she is shortening her sentence from Belle Reve. What is happening?

Answer (score -2):

There's a growing fan-theory that all the events in Harley's solo adventures will turn out to be just 'in her head' and that she's actually still in Belle Reve. Having followed Harley's Rebirth from the start I can believe that.

Comment: What evidence is there to support this?

Comment: In what way? Do you want details of some of the sites that mention it?

Comment: No, I want evidence from the comics that'd support this theory. If those sites are getting this out of the blue, it has no place as an answer here, since we welcome evidence-based and not purely speculative answers.