# DC S.C/H.Q: How can Harley Quinn be living on Coney Island and be In Belle Reve at the same time?

Tags: dc, comics, suicide-squad, harley-quinn

I'd not read any new Harley stuff till this week, when I read the Harley Quinn: Joker Loves Harley Arc. Then I started Justice League vs. Suicide Squad and 2 issues in it suddenly occurred to me that if Harley is still part of Task Force X how is she living on Coney Island?
Is Harley Quinn set years before/after Suicide Squad or does no one care because it's a comedy book?

Comment: Related (?): [What is happening with Harley Quinn in rebirth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/138583/70236) ~No answers though.

Comment: Out-of-universe? Suicide Squad and Harley Quinn are both (presumably) selling well enough that there's no particular incentive to rock the boat. Pure supposition, admittedly - no evidence to back it up.

Comment: Thanks for the link. That seems plausible, I didn't know if maybe that was laid out in the 1st issue which I obv didn't read. Dream world makes more sense then 'Red Tool' being real and monsters in the basement etc etc.

And it's crazy them doing a Deapool piss take. Deadpool was a piss take of Deathstroke to begin with so So then Red Tool being a spoof of him could be then start of a never ending spoofloop between marvel and DC.